# Pipe Invert Elevation

Tags: civil-engineering, pipelines

Can someone please help and explain if the invert elevation of the pipe is calculated as 192+2+10? or 192+2+10+0.6667 (8" pipe)? Or 192+2+10+1 (measured to bottom)? Sketch is not to scale. [image]

Comment: Not sure if this question is incredibly basic and the answer is 192' - 2' - 10' - 1' to bottom of pipe Or if I'm missing a weird subtlety around american notations for elevation.

Comment: So, the invert elevation means the elevation is measured to the bottom of the pipe instead of the top?

Comment: yes just google pipe invert, plenty of pics that explain invert, overt etc

Answer (score 1):

Actually none of your options are correct in my opinion, and that is **NOT** just because I am Canadian and you are **NOT** using the metric system.  When you want to give the invert of a pipe, or box culvert, you are measuring to the inside of the pipe and the lowest point on said pipe.  The reason your possible answers are not correct, is that you are going in the wrong direction.  You start at elevation 192 and you are going down, not up.  So it would be:

```
192'-2'-10'-1'=179'
```

TIP:  Your storm sewer pipe invert elevation should almost always never be above your road elevation.

There is no need to worry about the wall thickness of the pipe when calculating the invert unless its part of your chain of dimensions you are using.  In your sketch this is not a factor.

Comment: My bad, should be (-) instead of (+). Thanks for the explanation!